# proof of relation between euler's totient and pillai's arithmetical function

Tags: number-theory

[ P ( n ) = ∑ gcd(k,n) for k=1 to n

is equivalent to

```
 P(n)=∑d * φ(n/d) for all d such that d is divisor of n and phi is euler totient function.
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHPmg.png)

Comment: For more proof references see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillai%27s_arithmetical_function).

Comment: i asked for the proof and the question u linked only states the relation but gives no proof.

Comment: Wikipedia gives 4 proofs (see references).